# CakePHP 2.1: Sluggable Behavior with German Umlauts

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, slug

I am using Marino Iglesias' SluggableBehavior to generate slugs while saving entries. 
Now, since my blog will also have some German posts, slugging should also work with Umlauts such as ä,ü,ö. E.g., "Schöne neue Welt" should become "schoene-neue-welt".

Right now, it becomes "sch-ne-neue-welt". I am thoroughly using utf-8 as my encoding - files, database, everything, so that should not be the reason.

I do not really understand what happens in the code, but the conversion between ö to oe for example should be included, from what I see in the code.

Anybody has ever dealt with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should not be a problem with any of the newer versions.

try this one:
https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/Model/Behavior/SluggedBehavior.php

I use it in all projects without issues.

Comment: For Cake3 its in here: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/cake3/src/Model/Behavior/SluggedBehavior.php

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I assume that you're using the Cake2 compatible version [CakePHP-Sluggable-Behaviour](https://github.com/pronique/CakePHP-Sluggable-Behavior) by [pronique](https://github.com/pronique).

You can pass an option `translation` when adding it to your model like this.

```
var $actsAs = array(
  'Sluggable.Sluggable' => array(
    'translations' => 'utf-8',
  ),
);
```

Still this doesn't work for me, too. I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/pronique/CakePHP-Sluggable-Behavior/issues/1) for this and use the behavior already recommended by mark.